# Extract title in nested JSONObject cpprest/casablanca

Tags: json, rest, cpprest-sdk

I have a json file like this:

```
{
"company1": 
{
"id": "123456",
"created": "2019"
},

"company2":
{
"id": "223424",
"created": "2020"
}
}
```

I'm using cpprest library for handle json data and REST API.
for accessing the id and created field in above json we can easily do this:

```
jsonObject[U("company1")].at(U("created")).as_string()
```

But how i can find company name, if i don't have them or how i can get created and id value without knowing company names?

I didn't find it on their [wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/JSON) also.

Answer (score 0):

It was straightforward!

For finding Company name iterate over JsonObject and then key value is the company names. [Source](http://ramvellanki.github.io/blog/2016/05/15/working-with-casablanca-cpprestsdk/)

```
 const json::value& v = previousTask.get();
for (auto iter = v.as_object.cbegin(); iter != v.as_object.cend(); ++iter)
              {
                  const json::value &key = iter->first;


               }
```